# Asp.net Web Application Error During Compiling

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

Hello im currently making a webshop with asp.net, i was doing the exact same thing as the video tutorial on youtube, and suddenly the error appeared and i couldn't continue with the tutorial.
I am using Visual Studio 2019 and the video is from 2014.

**Here is the link to the tutorial**

The code he writes on minute 15:30 created the error for me, until that moment everything was working fine.
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SFDQ6Lkp8Ec&t=1265s

**Here is the Code of Product.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Webshop3.Models;

namespace Webshop3.Pages
{
    public partial class Product : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public string Price { get; private set; }
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public string Description { get; private set; }
        public string Image { get; private set; }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FillPage();
        }

        private void FillPage()
        {
            // marim te dhenat e produktit te selektuar
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["id"]))
            {
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
                ProductModel productModel = new ProductModel();
                Product product = productModel.GetProduct(id);

                // Mbushet faqja me data
                lblPrice.Text = "Price per unit: <br/>$" + product.Price;
                lblTitle.Text = product.Name;
                lblDescription.Text = product.Description;
                lblItemNr.Text = id.ToString();
                imgProduct.ImageUrl = "~/Images/Products/" + product.Image;

                // Mbushe dropdownList me numrat 1-20
                int[] amount = Enumerable.Range(1, 20).ToArray();
                ddlAmount.DataSource = amount;
                ddlAmount.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
                ddlAmount.DataBind();
            }

        }


    }
}
```

**Here is the Code of ManageProducts.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Webshop3.Models;

namespace Webshop3.Pages.Management
{
    public partial class ManageProducts : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                GetImages();

                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["id"]))
                {
                    int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
                    FillPage(id);
                }


            }


        }

        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ProductModel productModel = new ProductModel();
            Product product = CreateProduct();

            //testojme nese url ka parameter id
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["id"]))
            {

                // ID existon -> update rreshtin ekzistes
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
                lblResult.Text = productModel.UpdateProduct(id, product);
            }

            else
            {
                // nese nuk ekziston ID , krijo rresht te ri
                lblResult.Text = productModel.InsertProduct(product);
            }
        }

        private void FillPage(int id)
        {
            //Marim produktin e selektuar nga databaza
            ProductModel productModel = new ProductModel();
            Product product = productModel.GetProduct(id);


            //Mbushim textboxat
            txtDescription.Text = product.Description;
            txtName.Text = product.Name;
            txtPrice.Text = product.Price.ToString();


            ddlImage.SelectedValue = product.Image;
            ddlType.SelectedValue = product.TypeId.ToString();
        }

        private void GetImages()
        {
            try
            {
                // Marim Images te Dropdown
                string[] images = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Products/"));

                // Vendoj FileName ne arraylist

                ArrayList imageList = new ArrayList();
                foreach (string image in images)
                {
                    string imageName = image.Substring(image.LastIndexOf(@"\", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1);
                    imageList.Add(imageName);
                }

                ddlImage.DataSource = imageList;
                ddlImage.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
                ddlImage.DataBind();

            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                lblResult.Text = e.ToString();
            }

        }

        private Product CreateProduct()
        {
            Product product = new Product();
            product.Name = txtName.Text;
            product.Price = Convert.ToInt32(txtPrice.Text);
            product.TypeId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlType.SelectedValue);
            product.Description = txtDescription.Text;

            product.Image = ddlImage.SelectedValue;

            return product;
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the Compiler Error Before I press compile**

[image: The compiler Error before i press compile]

**Here is  compiler error before after I press compile**

[image: The compiler Error after I press compile]

Comment: That means you have two classes called  `Product` in two different namespaces and you're trying to use the wrong one here `Product product = productModel.GetProduct(id);` or you're returning the wrong one in the `GetProduct` method.

Comment: You are trying to assign the product poco type to the product page type. If you use `var`, the error will likely dissapear: `var product = productModel.GetProduct(id);`

Comment: On ManageProducts.Aspx.cs this error appeared https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVNFr.png